# fetching data from too many record with some condition in SQL

Tags: c#, android, sql, large-data

I'm trying to fetch data from a table in sql with a condition using C#. I developed an android application using c# and it has a list and the main activity which fetches new rows from a table in sql, and whenever the user scrolls down, it takes a few seconds to load. Is there any possible way to improve the the fetching of these new rows so the user wont have to wait few seconds?

Comment: what you should do is make your query to return results faster... use indexing or check your query add hints etc etc... cant suggest much without seeing exact database details... and yes its mostly to do with sql and nothing to do with c#

Comment: i'm using Linq to Sql in c#, according what you said i'll have to use view or storeprocedure, right? i have an ID that it is index and my query condition is on datetime type. here is my row structure : ID as int , title as nvarchar(50) , publishDate as datetime . i want select rows where publishDate is bigger than my parameter of query.

Comment: add another index on publish-date... you can configure index for any table thru code as well. I am not sure how would you provide hints though.. just google around it

Comment: thanks for your answer. i'll test this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SELECT TOP 1 and whenever the user scrolls down more, it executes the query which selects top 1 row. Also use FULLTEXT INDEXES.

Comment: can you explain more about "FULLTEXT INDEXES".

Comment: Ye, your performance will increase slightly by using SELECT TOP.

Comment: Also remember putting an order by statement so it wont return the same row everytime.